# Connect to AWS EC2 Instance through Cloud 9

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sftp, cloud9-ide

How do you connect to an AWS EC2 instance through [Cloud 9](http://c9.io)? Not through the console, but through mounting it, so that I can view the file tree.

I went to the dialog to mount an SFTP server, but there was no option for a key, and when I filled in the form, it was not able to connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get your SSH key from the Cloud9 dashboard when you select your workspace and put that on your trusted keys list of your AWS instance.